# Validate uniqueness of two filed but avoid if second one is null

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-3

i want to validate uniqueness of two filed  but if second filed is nil just ignore validation
i have two model 
'Asset' and 'Company'
Asset has an unique identifier code what i want to do is to validate uniqueness of identifier code of asset with company.
we can check this by

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :identifier, :uniqueness => {:scope => :company_id} 
end
```

but this also did not allow nil for two asset

how can i ignore validation of uniqueness of identifier code if its nil

can we pass a block,or add `except` or something like that we can do with filters in controller i am looking for some solution like

> validates :identifier, :uniqueness => {:scope => :company_id} unless { :identifier.is_nil? }

can i skip validation by some before-validation callback??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ruby 1.8.7

```
validates :identifier, :uniqueness => { :scope => :company_id } , :unless => lambda { |asset| !asset.identifier.nil? }
```

Ruby 1.9.3

```
   validates :identifier, :uniqueness: { scope: :company_id }, unless: lambda { |asset| !asset.identifier.nil? }
```

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me in Rails 4.0.1:

```
validates_uniqueness_of  :identifier, :scope => :company_id, :allow_blank => true
```

I could create objects with blank *identifiers* but could not create two objects with same identifier inside the same *company*.

PS: I know this was posted a long time ago, but this way of doing it looks also good. Here's the
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167223/validation-to-ensure-uniqueness-of-but-ignoring-empty-values) to a similar posterior question where I found the answer.