# Validation to ensure uniqueness of but ignoring empty values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following model field validation:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :acronym, :scope => [:group_id], :case_sensitive => false
```

The problem is that this field is optional, and a empty/nil value is returning as being an acronym already taken. I only want to validate that an acronym is unique if a value was provided.. Is there a way to update this validation to only take place if there is an actual value.. not nil/empty?

Thanks

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Yes, there are two possible options that you can pass to validations for optional fields: `:allow_blank` or `:allow_nil`, which will skip the validations on `blank` and `nil` fields, respectively. If you change your validation to the following, you should get the behaviour you want:

```rb
validates_uniqueness_of :acronym, :allow_blank => true, :scope => [:group_id], :case_sensitive => false
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! My code got a lot more comprehensive. Other answers suggested using :unless or :if, but I think this is the best way. Any issue in letting :group_id out of the array?

Comment: The spec for this is `it { is_expected.to validate_uniqueness_of(:acronym).scoped_to(:group_id).case_insensitive.allow_blank }`