# Rails how to validate optional form field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation

I have an optional form field `:meetup_apikey` and a custom validation method `api_key_valid?` to check if the API request returned is successful. But I only want to check for validation if the `meetup_apikey` form field is not empty (user entered something on form submit). If the `meetup_apikey` form field is empty, I want to ignore the validation and allow the form to save.

Looked at: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/activerecord_validations_callbacks.html documentation and [Validation to ensure uniqueness of but ignoring empty values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167223/validation-to-ensure-uniqueness-of-but-ignoring-empty-values).

This is what I have in my model:

```
validates :meetup_apikey, allow_blank: true
validates :api_key_valid?, :if => :meetup_apikey

def api_key_valid?
    url = "https://api.meetup.com/2/events?key=#{meetup_apikey}&sign=true&photo-host=public&group_urlname=#{meetup_urlname}"
    if !HTTParty.get(url).success?
    errors.add(:meetup_apikey, "Meetup API key must be valid")
    end
end
```

But this still forces the check, even if nothing is entered in the `:meetup_apikey` form field. I'm not sure what I am missing or writing wrong.

Any suggestions would help. Thanks!

Comment: You can add a question mark after the attribute's name to test its presence (`"".present?` returns `false`). `validates :api_key_valid?, :if => :meetup_apikey?`

Comment: Thank you @MrYoshiji, this worked for me, it was shorter and easier to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you'd apply `api_key_valid?` validation only if `meetup_apikey` attribute is non-blank:

```
validates :api_key_valid?, unless: ->(x) { x.meetup_apikey.blank? }
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. It was a little harder to understand `unless: ->(x) { x.meetup_apikey.blank? }`. But I could tell that the code does  `:api_key_valid?` validation unless `:meetup_apikey` is blank (not filled in).

Comment: @tshckr you're right, it basically means `unless: ->(the_object_i_am_validating) { the_object_i_am_validating.meetup_apikey.blank? }` :) It is the way to hook into the context of the object you're validation